# C# string.this int ' cannot be assigned to (it is read-only) REPLACE

Tags: c#

I want to change char 'R' to 'D' without (replace options && and without use any arrays or stringbuilder)

```
static void ex2()
{
    string body = "ABCDRTRTTRTT";
    for (int i = 0; i < body.Length; i++)
    {
        if (body[i]=='r')
        {
            body[i] = 'd';
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(body);
}
```

Comment: Copy every character to a new string, instead of trying to overwrite it.

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: Strings in C# cannot be modified. What are you trying to do, and where do the limitations in the requirements come from?

Answer (score 2):

Without `replace`,`StringBuilder` or `Array` you can create new temp string as following:

```
string body = "ABCDRTRTTRTT";
string tempBody = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < body.Length; i++)
{
    if (body[i] == 'R')
    {
        tempBody += 'D';
    }
    else
    {
        tempBody += body[i];
    }
}
body = tempBody;
Console.WriteLine(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

To update your current variable `body` you should to change type from `string` to `char[]`.

This code works:

```
char[] body = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'R' };
for (int i = 0; i < body.Length; i++)
{
    if (body[i] == 'r')
    {
       body[i] = 'd';
    }
 }
```

At the end, if you want to have a `string` variable, you just need to call the `ToString()` method:

```
string bodyString = body.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `Replace` or `StringBuilder` in a single line with LINQ:

```
string body = "ABCDRTRTTRTT";
var result = body.Select(c => c == 'R' ? 'D' : c);
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

> The string is immutable in .NET

- this is why you get the error.
  **Suggestion:**
  You can get a reverse string with LINQ